# In IDEA 13.1 test classes are not updated

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, intellij-idea

I've updated to IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 yesterday and I have a problem running unit test in a maven project. The tests work fine if compiling whole project but when I modify a code and run a single test(or single test class), the changes in the code are not reflected. I see the message "make" in the progress bar on bottom of the screen, but it looks like nothing is actually compiled.

So I've tried to create a simple test case to verify the problem like this:

```
package my.company.project;
import org.junit.Test;
public class Bug {
@Test
public void testBug() throws Exception{
    String bug = "ABC";
    System.out.println(bug);
}
}
```

But when I wanted to run the test, I got a message that the class `my.company.project.Bug` was not found. When I compile the whole project, the test is ok.

- Problem appears on  version 135.475 (13.1)
- Previous version(OK) 133.696 (13.02)

Both are Ultimate

Comment: Report the issue in the IntelliJ's bug tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Same here. Probably bug. Use 13.0.X in the meantime...

Comment: I've filled a bugreport on their pages. I use old version and it is fine.

Comment: YouTrack item is: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122629